# Populate records from JSON in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column in my database that contains an array stored as text:

```
ID | My_data
 0 | [[A, 0.1], [B, 0.1]]
 1 | [[A, 3.2], [B, 1.1]]
 : |  :
99 | [[B, 0.2], [A, 4.4]]
```

note that the data in the array is not always stored in the same order.

I am interested in converting the records in the arrays so that they are columns in the database:

```
ID |   A |   B
 0 | 0.1 | 0.1
 1 | 3.2 | 1.1
 : |   : |   :
99 | 4.4 | 0.2
```

My understanding is that `json_populate_record` can be used if my array is in a json format like `{'a':0.1, 'b':0.1}` but my data is not in this format.

Does anyone know of a way to do this kind of data transformation?

Comment: It might be simplest to write a program to fetch, alter, and update the rows rather than try to do it as a query.

Comment: There's a whole ton of [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) that can get you there.

Answer (score 0):

I develop some solution, maybe will interest you:

```
-- #1st part
CREATE TYPE custom_record AS (id INT, A TEXT, B TEXT);

-- #2nd part
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_records()
  RETURNS SETOF custom_record AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    single_record RECORD;
    return_record custom_record%ROWTYPE;
    matches       TEXT [];
    single_match  TEXT;
    tmp           TEXT [];
    A             TEXT;
    B             TEXT;
  BEGIN
    FOR single_record IN SELECT *
                         FROM test LOOP
      A = NULL;
      B = NULL;
      matches = regexp_matches(single_record.my_data, '\[\[(.+)\], \[(.+?)\]\]');

      FOREACH single_match IN ARRAY matches LOOP
        tmp = string_to_array(single_match, ', ');
        IF tmp [1] = 'A'
        THEN
          A = tmp [2];
        ELSE
          B = tmp [2];
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      return_record.id = single_record.id;
      return_record.A = A;
      return_record.B = B;
      RETURN NEXT return_record;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- #3rd part
SELECT * FROM show_records()
```

---

Explanation:

**#1st part**

Create new type which will be returned by function.

**#2nd part**

Main function, which translating records to new structure, for more details go to docs.

**#3rd part**

Select translated rows.

---

Output:

```
tests=> select * from show_records();
 id |  a  |  b  
----+-----+-----
  1 | 0.1 | 0.1
  2 | 3.2 | 1.1
  3 | 4.4 | 0.2
(3 rows)
```